# "Remember passwords for sites" keeps getting unchecked on its own

Tags: firefox

Any idea why "Remember passwords for sites" option in Firefox 41 Options>Security would keep getting unchecked?

Comment: Does the machine connect to a domain?

Comment: Yes, it's on the domain.

Comment: Does the domain use a Firefox Group Policy template?

Comment: Should I be able to see this group policy in the GP editor and where exactly?